# Formatting list of dates and adding to list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of articles where a date is rendered on each article. However, the dates are strings and in the format "YYYY-MM-DD". I need to collect all the strings, pull out the month and day and turn the format in to "Oct 11", as an example.

I have a loop that collects all the strings / "dates" from the element on the articles and I have a loop that creates a date object from the strings,  pulls out the month and matches it to a hard coded array with month names and gets the day and saves it on a variable.

```
  const monthNames = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "maj", "jun",
  "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"];

  let $month = "";
  let $day = "";
  let newDate = [];

  $('.jobs-grid__enddate').each(function() {
    newDate.push($(this).text());
});
  $(newDate).each( function(i, obj) {
      let $date = new Date(obj);
      $month = monthNames[$date.getMonth()];
      $day = $date.getDate();
    })
  $('.jobs-grid__enddate').text(` ${$day} ${$month}`);
}
```

I can log the values I want to the console, but I can't put the dates back onto the article list. All I end up printing to the browser is the last date processed. 
I can see how this won't work, but I don't know how to make it work.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the date transformation and replace the date directly in your first loop:

```
const monthNames = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "maj", "jun",
"jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"];

let $month = "";
let $day = "";

$('.jobs-grid__enddate').each(function() {
  let $date = new Date($(this).text());
  $month = monthNames[$date.getMonth()];
  $day = $date.getDate();
  $(this).text(` ${$day} ${$month}`);
});
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you!